# How to bring text right to textfield in extjs4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a form panel with one text field. I want to do something like this:

```
fieldLabel : ___________________ in Kilos.
```

How can I bring in Kilos to the right side of the text field in extjs4?

Using `afterLabelTextTpl` does not cut it, I want it to show immediately after the textfield.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to display text just after a TextField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578246/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-text-just-after-a-textfield)

Comment: how to use that composite field! can u brief ur answer

Comment: This is not a duplicate as Extjs 4.1 does not completely support composite field anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what I do in my application:

```
{
    xtype: "fieldcontainer",
    layout: "column",
    width:  300,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "textfield",
            fieldLabel: "fieldLabel",
            width: 200
        },
        {
            xtype: "displayfield",
            value: "in Kilos",
            width: 100
        }
    ]
}
```