# How to display plain text in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a extJS window. I want to display some text or message which may be response of some server data. Can any body help me how to display ytext on ext JS window. What I need to edit in my code below.

```
var MyWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: "My Window",
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            layout: 'fit',
        });
        MyWin.show();
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578246/what-is-the-best-way-to-display-text-just-after-a-textfield) might help

Comment: html text or simple text?

Comment: Happy if you can show both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I preferred show server errors whit a simple window and html in it, like And-y shows you can set html of a window, you can do simply that using a function everywere like this:

```
 var errorShow = function (text) {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'window',
            title: 'Response error',
            modal:true,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            html:text,
            scrollable: 'y'
        }).show();
    };
    errorShow('<div style="text-align:center;"><h1>Server error</h1>'+
    '<text style="color:red; font-size:1.4em;">404 not found</text><br/>'+
    '<text style="color:blue;">www.error.com/img.jpg</text><br/>'+
    '<text style="color:blue;">Error requiring image</text></div>');
```

here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l6n) to show you.

Remember that you should use the same function during every error, setting dimentions on your need.
A modal window should be used, to ensure that it will be closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also Is it possible to do wrapping or something

Comment: You can do all you want inside it, only add html and css and you'll can do the trick

Comment: Ya, I got it. thanls

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `html` config to display plain text or html formated text in the `Ext.window.Window` and any other `Ext.Component`.
From the [ExtJs 5.1.3 documentation html config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.Component.html#cfg-html):

> An HTML fragment, or a Ext.dom.Helper specification to use as the
>   layout element content. The HTML content is added after the component
>   is rendered, so the document will not contain this HTML at the time
>   the render event is fired. This content is inserted into the body
>   before any configured contentEl is appended. Defaults to: ''

The working code looks like:

```
var MyWin = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: "My Window",
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    html: "with some plain text or <p> some html</p>"
});
MyWin.show();
```

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l6o) is a working fiddle with the code above.

Comment: Bad ideas. Adding this code:

    ,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'component',
                    html: 'lalala'
                }
            ]
to code above makes it a "not working code"

Comment: It works as expected, you can either have html or items definition, not both. The items definition has predence over the html one.